# Connection Error with Mongoose working with Mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I was following a tutorial where i am moving from using Mongodb driver to mongoose. 
So far it worked at the beginning and suddenly i have this error in the console and I don't know where to start since it doesn't give me any clue (to my knowledge) where the problem is.

`{ MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cursonode-shard-00-02-wy13l.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/marcosdipaolo/Documents/sitios/node-tut/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at _handle.close (net.js:567:12)
    at TCP.done [as _onclose] (_tls_wrap.js:356:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }`

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb ?

Comment: Check IP whitelist

Comment: It was my ip provider changing my ip address every day..., solved, thanks.