# Connection error "TransientTransactionError" in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

Getting an error while connecting:

> {
>       "message" : "failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]",
>       "stack" : "Error: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]" +
>                 "at Pool. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\nosqlbooster4mongo\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)" +
>                 "at emitOne (events.js:115:13)" +
>                 "at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)" +
>                 "at Connection. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\nosqlbooster4mongo\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:317:12)" +
>                 "at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)" +
>                 "at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)" +
>                 "at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)" +
>                 "at Socket. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\nosqlbooster4mongo\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:246:50)" +
>                 "at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)" +
>                 "at emitOne (events.js:115:13)" +
>                 "at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)" +
>                 "at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)" +
>                 "at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)" +
>                 "at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)",
>       "name" : "MongoNetworkError",
>       "errorLabels" : [
>           "TransientTransactionError"
>       ]
>   }

Comment: may be you can try below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb

Comment: Right. " had the same issue/error, albeit on a Windows machine. Even though I thought I had started the mongodb service, I didn't see it running in Windows Services. So, I manually started the mongoDB service inside Services and then the error went away. Hope this helps!" That was the solution on my case