# MongoNetworkError : transienttransactionerror. Can't connect to atlas cluster through nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Database code:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const mongoConnect = callback => {
MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://shubhamt10:shubham123@cluster0-g2s9w.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
{ useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(client => {
console.log('Connected!');
callback(client);
})
.catch(err => {
console.log(err);
});
}
```

module.exports = mongoConnect;

app.js code

```
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database');

mongoConnect(client => {
console.log(client);
app.listen(3000);
});
```

I am getting this error :
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-g2s9w.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket. (E:\Node JS\Final Project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:611:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:390:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb on my case I restarted the MongoDB Service on Windows and it was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Please check the network access Of your MongoDB atlas account

[image]

click on the Allow access from anywhere button after that click on confirm button to change the IP address 0.0.0.0/0 now you can use your connection string on any system