# Mongoose is not connecting MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

This is the first time I use MongoDB Atlas to work with Mongo, and while trying to connect, that's the error I get:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.209.60.172:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://johnnybox:<password>@cluster0-cgxqx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { 
  useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(require('./routes'));

app.listen(3331);
```

ps* I'm not missing my credentials

Already looked for a solution here but there's nothing similar to my problem.

My whitelist:

[image]

Comment: Remove ```&w=majority``` from the end of the ```uri``` part of ```mongoose.connect()```. If it didn't work, bring your ```mongoose.connect()``` before ```app.listen()``` and after any ```app.use()```. Let me know if it works this time.

Comment: nothing changed Matin, even removing `&w=majority` and repositioning... :/

Comment: according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956063/11330560) it all comes down to IP issue in the end (and I know you tried). Perhaps you're using VPN or some proxy that hinders it. Or perhaps it is your ISP. Also change the region of your cluster to anywhere in US.

Comment: I now realized you might be mixing up your own MongoDB username with the "database user" you made. see if you're using database user and password you made yourself. Let me know.

Comment: i found out the problem guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run this code at home and it worked perfectly!

So it was something here in my office, after some testing, the problem was with the connection port that was locked.

Take a look:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.209.60.172:27017
```

Note that it connects to the port `27017`

**The Ip is random, so it changes after every requisition.

After my Sd opened this port, everything worked properly!!

[image]

Thanks so much for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://{my_user}:{mypass}@johnnybox-cgxqx.mongodb.net/johnnybox?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: got this error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.214.209.13:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}`

Comment: what's your database name?

Comment: it's "johnnybox"

Comment: then on mongoose connection `mongodb+srv://{my_user}:{mypass}@johnnybox-cgxqx.mongodb.net/johnnybox`  should be enough

Comment: are you using mongodb compass?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194611/discussion-between-joao-vitor-and-afrida-anzum-aesha).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your IP Address in the mongo atlas IP Whitelist.
Otherwise accept every connections if you don't need secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer to the new error:

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb/54956063#54956063), which had the same exact error, that is:

```
'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]:
```

Add your current IP to whiteList following "clusters/security/whitelist" in MongoDB website.

I'm sorry, I spent at least an hour to solve this. That's all I can do.

---

Old answer addressing the former error (he fixed this part, but still got a new error):

If you read the error log carefully it says:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block
```

That means you needed to add `catch()` to your mongoose connection:

`mongoose.connect({some code}).then({some code}).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: i updated my question using just like Afrida told, but the error changed

Comment: @JoãoVitor Sorry, I didn't read her answer while trying to solve your problem.

Comment: thats ok matin, my question is now with the updated error and catch block aswell

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who tried various URIs the only thing that got it working here is **to Add you IP** vs **allow the access from anywhere**. Hope that saves you some time.