# Can not connect on Mongodb port 27017

Tags: mongodb

Out of nowhere, I get this error.

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-erhon.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-01-erhon.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at connect (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at callback (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:109:5)
    at runCommand (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:129:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:321:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:350:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:1854) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-erhon.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-01-erhon.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at connect (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at callback (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:109:5)
    at runCommand (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:129:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:321:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/theodosiostziomakas/nodejs-tutorials/09_Working with MongoDB/07_Finishing the Update Product code/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:350:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
(node:1854) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1854) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I am using Mongo Atlas(meaning I have mongodb installed), and here is how I connect with mongodb.

```
const mongoConnect = callback => {
   MongoClient
   .connect('mongodb+srv://theodosiostziomakas:password_goes_here@cluster0-erhon.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
   {useNewUrlParser: true}
   )
   .then(client => {
      console.log('Connected!');
      _db = client.db();
      callback();
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
   });
}
```

You can also download my project from this [repo](https://github.com/theo82/NodeJs-Eshop).

How can this error be fixed? I also looked in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec), but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an error is usually **IP issue**.

First of all, You have to whitelist your IP.
Even if you mention that you did whitelist your IP, there must be some **external factor** that influencing, **changing your IP / port** (reconnecting to wifi, ISP, etc.)

And to know whether the fault lies in your code alone, try connecting your MongoDB cluster through `MongoDB Compass`. If it connects, then it's from your code.

Also make sure you didn't use your own MongoDB username and password but username and password you created in `Security -> Database Access`.

---

Links to other questions that had faced exactly your error, which all in the end was IP issue:

[Mongoose is not connecting MongoDB Atlas (the answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551688/11330560)

[Couldn't connect to mongodb on mongodb-atlas(the answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56649506/11330560)