# MongoDB Atlas connection error "failed to connect to server..."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I am trying to perform a connection to mongodb using mongoose but it throws an error.
Here is my code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-bocic.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true", {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(()=>console.log("Database connected..."))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Here is the error:

```
[0] { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-bocic
.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster
0-shard-00-01-bocic.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
[0]     at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_modules\mo
ngodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:431:11)
[0]     at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
[0]     at connect (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_modules\mongodb-cor
e\lib\connection\pool.js:557:14)
[0]     at callback (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_modules\mongodb-co
re\lib\connection\connect.js:109:5)
[0]     at runCommand (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_modules\mongodb-
core\lib\connection\connect.js:129:7)
[0]     at Connection.errorHandler (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_mod
ules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:321:5)
[0]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
[0]     at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
[0]     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Med\Desktop\jutsuapp\myapp\node_modul
es\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:350:12)
[0]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
[0]     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
[0]     at _handle.close (net.js:610:12)
[0]     at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)
[0]   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
[0]   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[0]   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Please post all the versions you're using (mongoose, node, etc.). Have you also whitelisted your IP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a TransientTransactionError in Mongoose (or MongoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb)

Comment: I have `"mongoose": "^5.6.2"`, `"express": "^4.17.1"` in my package.json, node`v10.15.0`. I have whitelisted my ip

Comment: Nevermind I think it was coming from ip whitelist

Comment: I ran into this error too. It was an ip whitelist issue for me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got to solve the same problem: in the last three days my applications (node.js, express, mongoose, graphql) got connected to the mongoDB (in the cloud) whithout any problem, but today I got:

*Error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-cpkkj.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-00-cpkkj.mongodb.net:27017 closed]*

I verified the IP of my PC and that's it: it has changed and is not more the same IP I added to the Whitelist, so I added the new one and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to enable any host connection access, you can set to the whitelist in atlas configuration the following IP address:

- 0.0.0.0

Then, even when your IP address suddenly changes, you might still connect.