# Getting error while connecting to mongoDB database using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I am getting the following error while connecting the mongoDB database present in MLAB using Node.js.

```
Error in DB connection : {
  "name": "MongoNetworkError",
  "errorLabels": [
    "TransientTransactionError"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authData =  {
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "useCreateIndex": true
};
//connecting local mongodb database named test
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb://subhra:*****@ds139989.mlab.com:39989/hlloyd',
  {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err)=>{
    if (!err) 
      console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.');
    else 
      console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Here my database is present inside `MLAB` but when I am tring to connect to that DB its throwing me that error. I need to connect to my database here.

Comment: do you have IP whitelist enabled for your account or something? sometimes it might happen for IP whitelisting as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a TransientTransactionError in Mongoose (or MongoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb)

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty: But I could not know how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

`"useCreateIndex": true` and `useUnifiedTopology: true` is deprecated .

Try out the following code to connect your mongoDB database .

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://subhra:*****@ds139989.mlab.com:39989/hlloyd', {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log("Connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your current IP  or  `0.0.0.0`  to whiteList following "main page > security section > network access > add IP" in MongoDB website.

I hope this helps.