# I can not connect to monogdb with mongoose when authorization enabled

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect with MongoDB by mongoose. Everything was ok, when I was connecting with my local db where there is no authentication.
When I've tried to connect to other DB with set admin user and credentials, I've got error and I've tried various different options but without any positive result. 
I use these versions:

```
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1"
```

And my server side technology is node.js

I've tried these options:

```
const connection = await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}/${db}?authSource=admin`,
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

then I've tried this:

```
 let options = {
   "auth": { "authSource":"admin"},
    "user": "SVSAdmin",
    "pass":"8&PG2DCUuDPvy$hx",
    "useUnifiedTopology": true, 
    "useNewUrlParser": true
  };

const connection = await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}/${db}, options);
```

and this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://${user}:${pass}@${uri}/${db}?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://${user}:${pass}@${uri}/${db}?authMechanism=MONGODB-CR')
```

and also this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@host/yourDB?authSource=admin&w=1')
```

but it does not work. My credentials are ok.

The error message is:

```
{
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Maybe important thing is that I'm connecting with db by ssh
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a TransientTransactionError in Mongoose (or MongoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb)

Comment: But these solutions does not work for me, I am not using MongoDB Atlas, I can not IP, beside it worked with the same IP when I've connected by mongodb

Comment: Verify You mongoDb= mongo -u AdminSammy -p --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot when I've tried like you've said it is connecting correctly

Comment: Without mongoose, it is happening?

Comment: No, without mongoose everything was ok.

Comment: I am using also ssh, maybe it is important information but during connecting from computer where db is running I've the same error, when I'm using mongoose

Comment: If u are using ur database remotly then u can use it via IP.

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot I've used IP, but when I was changing to `localhost`, it seems to be fixed. Thank you very much,  I've spent many hours with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are using ur database remotly then u can use it via IP.

```
db = mongodb://52.221.52.32/DataBaseName
```