# How to fix TransientTransactionError in Shard Mongo DB with spring boot?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, sharding

**Scenario:**

1. I am using Mongo DB 6+ version with spring boot.

```
 @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }
```

```
 @Transactional
    public void save(Cart cart,Item item) {
        Cart cartFromDB = cartRepo.findById(cart.getId());
        if(cartFromDB!= null){
            cart.setId(cartFromDB.getId());
            cartRepo.save(cart);
        }else{
            cartRepo.save(cart);
        }
        itemRepo.save(item);
    }
```

2. I am using `@Transactional` to save two different document in the same transaction.
3. I was having Mongo DB with replica set, it worked fine without any error..
4. Now Mongo DB has been changed to use sharding.
5. I suspect after this change, I am getting TransientTransactionError intermittently. After couple of tries manually its getting succeeded
6. When I implement retry it succeeded.

**Error message:**

`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13388 (StaleConfig): 'Transaction sd-ef6d-dsd-83bd-fsdfdf - dfdfdfdfdsdfdsfsd= -  - :1 was aborted on statement 2 due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error from mongodb.cluster.local:26009 during a transaction :: caused by :: sharding status of collection mongodb.item is not currently known and needs to be recovered' on server mongos.xxxx.com:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Transaction c43f42bd-ef6d-4c48-83bd-fgdfgsdfsgf - fgggeddddsksduydhdhsh= -  - :1 was aborted on statement 2 due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error from mongodb.cluster.local:26009 during a transaction ::..... "errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"]}`

**Question:**

- Is this something to do with sharding?
- Should I implement retry in
  the code as suggested by some other forums. eg
  [What is a TransientTransactionError in Mongoose (or MongoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb)

Comment: Can you confirm that all shards are running the same mongodb version?

Comment: Yes all are using 6.0.2 version of mongodb

Answer (score -1):

`TransientTransactionError` is considered a possibly temporary and retryable error as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52867766/9492730). So you may try to retry it manually in old style (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/core/transactions/#retry-transaction)) or better, and this way is recommended, to use a relatively new [method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.11/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/ClientSession.html#withTransaction(com.mongodb.client.TransactionBody)): `WithTransaction` that handles retry logic behind the scene. I didn't work with `spring-boot`, so not sure how it can be called there, so you have to investigate it additionally

Comment: Yes I can do retry but I am not able to understand why is it not happening in replica set without sharding cluster

Comment: you may search for more details (like https://copyprogramming.com/howto/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb#what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb), however from user's POV the important part is that it may occur and it's safe to retry it. But as I wrote, the recommended way is to delegate this logic to the driver and `WithTransaction` method (I posted a link on java impl above)