# multi document transactions error code 112 to mongoDB 5.0

Tags: mongodb

(mongoDB 5.0)

I'm getting this error message from time to time during heavy load from my application connected to mongoDB cluster:

```
{
"$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
            "i": 52,
            "t": 1706989145
        }
    },
    "signature": {
        "hash": {
            "$binary": {
                "base64": "fnvUliBEGFu7G03DJ7fjIH/ttLM=",
                "subType": "00"
            }
        },
        "keyId": 7273185051695644677
    }
},
"code": 112,
"codeName": "WriteConflict",
"errmsg": "Encountered error from mydatashard:27017 during a transaction :: caused by :: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.",
"errorLabels": [
    "TransientTransactionError"
],
"ok": 0.0,
"operationTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
        "i": 52,
        "t": 1706989145
    }
 }
}
```

Few questions if you could help:

1. Why there is nothing seen in the mongoDB cluster logs and how to improve logging to log also this error messages but not everything?
2. How I can reproduce this behaviour , attempting to write to same document via two separate sessions from shell:

   ```
   mongosh1>for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { var session1 = db.getMongo().startSession();session1.startTransaction();var cities = session1.getDatabase('test').getCollection('cities');cities.update( {"name" : "test" }, {$set: { "x" : 1 }},{multi:true});print(i);session1.commitTransaction();}
   mongosh2>for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { var session2 = db.getMongo().startSession();session2.startTransaction();var cities = session2.getDatabase('test').getCollection('cities');cities.update( {"name" : "test" }, {$set: { "x" : 2 }},{multi:true});print(i);session2.commitTransaction();}
   ```

is throwing me this error but not the above? :

```
   Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "064cf88c-b7b6-400f-b6e0-40311373f4d8:0 Failed to commit transaction because a 
    previous statement on the transaction participant myshard was unsuccessful.",
    "code" : 251,
    "codeName" : "NoSuchTransaction",
    "$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1707255782, 3670),
    "signature" : {
    "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
    "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
     }
     },
     "operationTime" : Timestamp(1707255782, 3670),
     "errorLabels" : [
     "TransientTransactionError"
      ]
      } with original command request: {
      "commitTransaction" : 1,
      "txnNumber" : NumberLong(0),
      "lsid" : {
      "id" : UUID("064cf88c-b7b6-400f-b6e0-40311373f4d8")
      },
     "$clusterTime" : {
      "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1707255782, 3669),
     "signature" : {
     "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
     "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
     }
     },
     "autocommit" : false,
     "stmtId" : NumberInt(1)
```

Comment: see some notes regarding `TransientTransactionError` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613843/9492730. I think, it can be expected behavior and you have to just retry it

Comment: see also https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-in-applications/#transienttransactionerror

Comment: `"codeName": "WriteConflict"`, `"errmsg": "Encountered error from mydatashard:27017 during a transaction :: caused by :: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction."` - See [In-progress Transactions and Write Conflicts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/#std-label-transactions-write-conflicts). And, you can do something about the error  (handle it) in your try-catch enclosing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your application is producing records as per your unique index keys (fields that you have mentioned in unique key index). I had the similar issue for having same timestamp in unique key for parallel persistence.

Comment: This does not answer the question.